# Apache POI append data to excel sheet not working

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading data from an arraylist and writing this to an excel sheet. The problem is my excel is getting overwritten each time. Here is my code. I can't figure out what is wrong here :( Can someone please help?

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
        List<String> fileData = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(File file:files) {
            fileData.add(readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        for(String fileContent:fileData) {
            //do some stuff that in turn calls the writeDataToExcel method 

    }
}

private static void writeDataToExcel(String test,Map<String,String> dataMap,Object object) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("input/data.xls");
    Map<String,Object[]> data = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object[]>();       
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null; 
    int count = 0;
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    if(file.exists()) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        sheet = workbook.getSheet("Data Sheet");
    }
    else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Sheet");
        //count = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    }

    data.put("1", new Object[]{"Id","Name","Field","Description","Value"});
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> dataMp:dataMap.entrySet()) {
        data.put(Integer.toString(count+2), new Object[]{id,object.getClass().getSimpleName(),dataMp.getKey(),dataMp.getValue(),"null"});
        count++;
    }
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
             if(obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("input/data.xls");
    workbook.write(fis);
    if(fis!=null)
        fis.close();
}
```

Comment: @rgettman - Can you please help me?

Comment: When you say "my excel is getting overwritten" what precisely do you mean?  Something like rows in Excel, or the whole  workbook?

Comment: @Levenal - The whole workbook is getting overwritten.

Comment: You appear to be blindly starting at row 0 and overwriting data, shouldn't you instead find the first free row and start from there?

Comment: Are you able to clarify exactly what is happening,  if the whole workbook is being replaced that implies you are saving over the old one (In which case the bug is likely in the saving/opening of the wb)  If the sheet is being removed then maybe you are overwriting the sheet (So we look for the bug there) or as Gagravarr mentions, if you are losing data maybe you are unintentionally writing to the same cells each time.

Comment: I have created a new sheet and data is appended while I user-defined appendDataToCSV(). But when I try to get the "last row" of the same sheet in another function, I get ROW_COUNT as 0. Have to make the sheet store after data is getting appended.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is at line

```
int rownum = 0;
```

this will set `rowNUm` to zero each time and sheet will be written from zero row

You need to persist this `rowNum` value if you want to append data in the sheet